# Обобщения и интерфейсы

Tags: c#, .net

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, такое вот дело, читаю в книге такую вот фразу про реализацию обобщенных интерфейсов:

```
class ByTwos<T> : ISeries<T>
Параметр типа Т указывается не только при объявлении класса ByTwos, но и при
объявлении интерфейса ISeries. И это очень важно. Ведь класс, реализующий 
обобщенный вариант интерфейса, сам должен быть обобщенным.
```

Однако далее я нахожу такой вот участок кода:

```
class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>, IEquatable<MyClass>
```

И что самое главное - этот код работает, почему тогда вначале говорилось о том, что обязательно при подключении обобщенного интерфейса необходимо передавать его параметры типа?

Спасибо.

Comment: Читаете Шилдта, небось? Он не всегда отвечает за свои слова. :)

Comment: Да, именно его и читаю. С Вами полностью согласен. А еще иногда он, ничего не объяснив про какую-нибудь возможность, использует её, словно все телепаты и с рождения об этом уже знали. )))

Comment: ну так читайте другие книги - благо их много

Comment: Да, я с Вами согласен, но у Шилдта есть одно важное преимущество - он объясняет как для идиотов. А мне это очень нужно, потому как я начинал вначале с Троелсена, и там все было сложно для человека, который ранее даже понятия не имел о программировании. Поэтому, к сожалению, альтернативы я пока не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Обязательно" - там имеется ввиду, что мы должны указывать `ISeries<T>`, `ISeries<int>`, `ISeries<string>` и т.п, а не просто писать `ISeries`. Согласен, фраза неоднознача.

По поводу generics:
`ISeries<T>` - как некоторые называют - это открытый тип, имеющий тип-аргумент T, который может быть любым, если нет ограничений; а `ISeries<int>` - это уже закрытый тип - тип, имеющий конкретный тип-аргумент int.

Покажу на простом "бессмысленном" примере, как это используется:

Допустим, имеется generic-интерфейс *IMyInterface* с одним параметром-обобщения *T*. Интерфейс имеет один член - это свойство *MyProperty* типа *T*:

```
interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Например, нам поставили задачу спроектировать обобщенный класс *A*, который будет реализовывать интерфейс *IMyInterface*. Мы сделаем так:

```
class A<T> : IMyInterface<T>
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
    // остальной код
}
```

Далее нам ставят задачу спроектировать необобщенный класс *B*, имеющий свойство MyProperty типа int, и чтобы он реализовывал интерфейс IMyInterface<T>. Мы делаем так:

```
// ошибка
class B : IMyInterface<T>
{
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
   // остальной код
}
```

И у нас будет ошибка, т.к. класс *B* необобщенный, про тип *T* он ничего не знает, и в тоже время он должен реализовать свойство MyProperty типа T. 
Чтобы выполнить задачу, мы должны "закрыть" IMyInterface конкретным типом-аргументом, в нашем случае это int, т.е.:

```
class B : IMyInterface<int>
{
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
   // остальной код
}
```

Какой вывод можно сделать?
Когда мы создаем generic-класс, реализующий generic-интерфейс, то, конечно, в интерфейс мы передаем тип-аргумента класса, который может быть любым типом (если, конечно, не имеются ограничения).
Если мы создаем уже необобщенный класс и должны реализовать generic-интерфейс, то в этот интерфейс мы должны передать конкретный тип-аргумента, грубо говоря из generic'а-интерфейса сделать обычный.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все очень четко, доступно и понятно!